# .text section not readable

Tags: virtual-memory

I was looking at the `/proc/<pid>/maps` file for an aarch64 process running on an Android (10).  This section caught my interest:

```
72582d2000-72582f6000 --xp 00012000 07:20 93        /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so
```

According to `readelf`, that corresponds, as expected, to the `.text` section.

What does it mean for a memory section to be executable but not readable?  I didn't think that was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute-only memory (XOM) was a security feature added in Android 10 and then removed in Android 11.

According to [this reference](https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/execute-only-memory), it was implemented "as a hardening mitigation against just-in-time code reuse attacks."